# Parallel decomposition of independent async tasks with kotlin coroutines

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to run multiple tasks in parallel, but the tasks are independent so if one of children coroutine fails, I do not want its siblings or parent to fail too. In the code below I have used coroutineScope to create a new scope in which these tasks run and launched 5 async tasks each on sending its id and the delay time it should wait. The second coroutine throws an exception. In this case the code does what i want it to do, it calculates the sum of the jobs that successfully finished and the ones that failed return 0.

However, I am reading that there is also supervisorScope in the kotlinx library which should be preferred instead of coroutineScope (which cancels parent/siblings if exception is not handled) for tasks are not dependent on others. I am not sure why I should be changing to use supervisorScope as I am getting the result I want with coroutineScope.

**Q1**: If i were to change to supervisorScope should something change in my async blocks?

**Q2**: Is it accepted to catch any exception inside the async block and dont let anything be propagated to its parent? I know you can also catch exceptions during .await() phase but is that the way it should be done?

```
runBlocking {
    coroutineScope {
            val job1 = async<Int> {
                try {
                    request(1, 1000)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println("Job 1 failed with $e")
                    0
                }
            }

            val job2 = async<Int> {
                try {
                    request(2, 2000)
                    throw Exception("cancelling Job 2")
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println("Job 2 failed: $e")
                    0
                }
            }

            val job3 = async {
                try {
                    request(3, 3000)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println("Job 3 failed with $e")
                    0
                }
            }

            val job4 = async {
                try {
                    request(4, 4000)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println("Job 4 failed with $e")
                    0
                }
            }

            val job5 = async {
                try {
                    request(5, 5000)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println("Job 5 failed with $e")
                    0
                }
            }

            val result = job1.await() + job2.await() + job3.await() + job4.await() + job5.await()
            println(result.toString())
        }

        println("Finished")
}
```

```
suspend fun request(id: Int, time: Long): Int {
    println("Job $id started")
    delay(time)
    println("Job $id finished")
    return id
}
```

Comment: Yes, a typo here

Answer (score 1):

The reason all coroutines run to completion is that you `catch` the exception thrown by job 2 within job 2 itself, so it never propagates up the hierarchy of `Job`s, so nothing happens.

However, if you remove that `catch` clause in job2, job[1-5] will always be canceled, independent of if you use `coroutineScope` or `supervisorScope`.

This is because `job2.await()` will throw the exception instead. Since this happens within the parent job of job[1-5] (i.e. within the top `coroutineScope`/`supervisorScope`), and since a failed/cancelled parent job always cancel child jobs, job[1-5] will also be cancelled.

**A1**: Use none of `coroutineScope` or `supervisorScope`, remove `coroutineScope` and put things directly under `runBlocking`.

**A2**: It certainly is allowed to catch exceptions within `async { }` to make sure it doesn't happen in `.await()` if it fits your use case.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So what is the approach to be taken? Should i always handle exception within the job itself and never allow it to propagate no matter if i use `coroutineScope` or `supervisorScope` or is there more idiomatic way to handle this?

Comment: I don't see why you need `coroutineScope` at all in this case. Keep doing what you do, i.e. catch exceptions in failing child jobs and make them return 0, then just sum them like you already do. Just remove your current `coroutineScope` and move everything up directly under `runBlocking` and you're done. (You might want to add some helper functions to reduce code duplication, of course. And you shouldn't use `runBlocking` in your real code either, of course, but I suspect you don't.)

Comment: Yes, this is just a sample code i came up with but the idea is similar, I just create async coroutines in a loop hence why i created a coroutineScope around them all. And yes, I dont use runBlocking in my code